# Firewire film scanner

Tags: firmware-analysis

There is firewire photo film scanner Konica-minolta (scanner part of the minilab) that is standard mashine vision firewire linescan camera, connected to controler that deal with motor film fee, light, switches and buttons. Mostly controler is transparent to the camera commands and intercept only controler commands. As usually there are no any documentation - its 10+ years  old (somewhere from 2006). 
  Question is how to reverse engineer commands sent from crappy windows xp software to the scanner? How to distinguish camera commands from controler commands? I dont know the camera model and cant imagine how to get it, may be by some command? I suppose that the camera support one of the standards for mashine vision, but which one? I tried to search for free or affordable firewire debbuging solutions, but no success. How to distinguish firewire commands (to/from scanner) from big data (ie image sent from scanner data's)? 
Final goal is to make linux standalone driver. Hope to have only useful answers.